# TeX-electric-macro not working in math mode

Tags: auctex

I feel like I must be very dumb, but here goes.

I have `TeX-electric-escape` (from auctex) set in order to use `TeX-electric-macro`, which works fine while entering text. It autocompletes predefined commands as well as ones from my preamble.

However, as soon as point is in math mode, the macro complains that it finds no possible completions for anything. Not for `\lambd`, nothing. It still autocompletes non-math macros in math mode though, which is clearly useless.

Is there either

- a way to make auctex autocomplete math macros
- or at least a way to disable the electric escape entirely while in math mode?

Here is the relevant part from my init file:

```
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq TeX-auto-regexp-list 'TeX-auto-full-regexp-list)
(setq TeX-auto-parse-length 999999)
;; make \ invoke the macro insertion thingy immediately
(setq TeX-electric-escape t)
```

Comment: Why don't you use LaTeX-math-mode (C-c ~) and `l to type \lambda ?

Comment: @gigiair Mostly because I only just started using auctex and did not know that exists. Sadly, that still does not solve my problem for all other math macros.
(Also, should auxtex not be able to guess on its own when I want math mode enabled?)

Comment: You can enable LaTeX-math-mode by default. See  : (info "(auctex)Entering Mathematics"). It add thhe menu-bar a math menu you can use to input math symbols .